# Android http post with composed objects

Tags: android, http, post

I'm trying to invoke a REST web service from Android with . For this purpose i created a class like this:

```
public class HttpUtils {
public static final String BASE_URL1 = AppConstants.hostname;
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);


public HttpUtils() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
}

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void getByUrl(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
}

public static void postByUrl(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.post(url, params, responseHandler);
}

private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
    return relativeUrl;
}
```

Then i created a service layer in order to call the method post. The customer gave me the structure of JSON to send:

```
{
"wsMode":"nuovo",
"wsTokenLogin":"&1I1BY!M$$YEMFKI0YX&",
"crmcttCognome": "Xavi",
"crmcttNome": "Alonso",
"crmcttIndirizzo": "via Alcide de Gasperi",
"crmcttCivico": "1",
"crmcttLocalita": "Napoli",
"crmcttCdLocalita": "",
"crmcttProv": "NA",
"crmcttCap": "80100",
"crmcttTel1": "08123232332",
"crmcttTel2": "",
"crmcttMobile1": "",
"crmcttMobile2": "",
"crmcttEmail1": "",
"crmcttEmail2": "",
"crmcttNota": "ok",
"crmcttIdstcontatto": "N",
"crmcttIdpromoter": "61",
"crmcttDtRilevaz": "20180806",
"crmcttOraRilevaz": "1530",
"crmcttLuogoRilevaz": "",
"prodotti": [{
    "crmcprIdprodotto": "01",
    "crmprdCdprodotto": "MATE",
    "crmprdDsprodotto": "MATERASSI"
}]}
```

The request i have created has the following structure:

```
   RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    rp.put("wsMode", "nuovo");
    rp.put("wsTokenLogin", token);
    rp.put("crmcttCognome", lead.getCognome());
    rp.put("crmcttNome", lead.getNome());
    rp.put("crmcttIndirizzo", lead.getIndirizzo());
    rp.put("crmcttCivico", lead.getCivico());
    rp.put("crmcttLocalita", lead.getLocalita());
    rp.put("crmcttCdLocalita", lead.getCdLocalita());
    rp.put("crmcttProv", lead.getProvincia());
    rp.put("crmcttCap", lead.getCap());
    rp.put("crmcttTel1", lead.getTelefono1());
    rp.put("crmcttTel2", lead.getTelefono2());
    rp.put("crmcttMobile1", lead.getMobile1());
    rp.put("crmcttMobile2", lead.getMobile2());
    rp.put("crmcttEmail1", lead.getEmail1());
    rp.put("crmcttEmail2", lead.getEmail2());
    rp.put("crmcttNota", lead.getNota());
    rp.put("crmcttIdstcontatto", lead.getIdContatto());
    rp.put("crmcttIdpromoter", lead.getIdPromoter());
    rp.put("crmcttDtRilevaz", lead.getDataRilevazione());
    rp.put("crmcttOraRilevaz", "");
    rp.put("prodotti",prodottiCliente);
    rp.setUseJsonStreamer(true);
```

where prodottiCliente is array of objects that i have transformed into String with:

```
 String jsonProdottiAddClient = gson.toJson(prodottiAddClient);
```

After the call, all elements are stored into db except "prodotti". In debug i can see that the list is not empty.

If i try to execute the post call by Postman, all information are stored including prodotti informations. Can you give me some advice to solve the problem?

Comment: What's the type of prodottiCliente object? Is it a Map<Sring, String>?

Comment: It’s ArrayList of objects that I transform in json with gson.toJson

Comment: As seen in your customer json format, and according to json syntax, prodotti is an array of length 1, shown by enclosing []. inside this array lies a map of string to string shown by enclosing {}. I suspect your prodottiCliente object is not structured this way.

Comment: In debug i can see something like this: [{"crmcprIdprodotto":"01","crmprdCdprodotto":"MATE","crmprdDsprodotto":"MATERASSI"},{"crmcprIdprodotto":"02","crmprdCdprodotto":"RETI","crmprdDsprodotto":"RETI"}]

Comment: I meant that you should check the type of the prodottiCliente instance in your Java code. is it a Map<String,String>?

Comment: After some hours, i understood that i needed StringEntity in order to send a JsonObject with a JSONArray linked to it.